# How to logically compare two XML files using java api?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to compare two XML files. I have tries with XMLUnit api. But it is not working for me as i want.
I want to that following comparison results in true i.e they are similar.

FILE1:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <node1> xyz </node1>
        <node2> abc </node2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node3>pqr</node3>
        <node4>stu</node4>
    </node>
</root>
```

FILE2:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <node3>pqr</node3>
        <node4>stu</node4>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node1> xyz </node1>
        <node2> abc </node2>
    </node>
</root>
```

I want this comparison to be equal = true.

My function:

```
public static void assertXMLSame(String path1,String path2){
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(Boolean.TRUE);

        FileReader fr1 = null;
        FileReader fr2 = null;
        try {
            fr1 = new FileReader(path1);
            fr2 = new FileReader(path2);
            Diff diff = new Diff(fr1,fr2);
            System.out.println("Similar? " + diff.similar());
            System.out.println("Identical? " + diff.identical());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us your code.

Comment: I have used org.custommonkey.xmlunit API.

Comment: How large is your XML? Is it ok to use DOM and keep both xml documents in memory. Than compare node by node for existance.

Comment: A better strategy would be convert it into Java Object using JAXB api, then you can compare the Java object easily by overriding the equals method

Answer (score 0):

If you know structure of you XML beforehand you could prepare class template for it. Your class should implement equals() method. Then unmarshal source xmls to java class instances and then you could test them for equality.